# file name with special letter(;) does not uploaded

Tags: filenames, onedrive

I'm using Live Connect REST API for uploading file to SkyDrive.

During I tested, file which contains special letter ";" were not uploaded.

below example is what I tested with ;.mp4

PUT  https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files/%3B.mp4?access_token=(access_token)

The response of the request is 
BAD_REQUEST(400).

";" letter is not acceptable in Sky Drive?

Please, let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ';' character (%3B) IS a valid OneDrive file name character. Unfortunately it appears as though, for whatever reason, the Live Connect API is not allowing it.